# How to get myTasks from mySite?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hello i try to get myTasks for the current User from sharepoint 2013. I tried it with the Rest-API and with JSON but i always get an error. Acording to the debugger `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded is undefined`.

Here is my little Javascript i got so far: (old)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sps10/EDV/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var context, userSessionManager ,userSession , query , myTasks ;
$(document).ready(function () {
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
       context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
           userSessionManager = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.UserOrderedSessionManager(context);
           userSession = userSessionManager.createSession();
           query = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.TaskQuery(context);
           myTasks = userSession.readTasks(query);
       }, "sp.workmanagement.js");
       getMyTasks();
   }, "sp.js");
});

function getMyTasks() {
    context.load(myTasks);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetMyTasksSuccess, onGetMyTasksFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
function onGetMyTasksSuccess() {
    console.log("Successfully retrieved tasks...");
    var taskEnumerator = myTasks.getEnumerator();
    while (taskEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var task = taskEnumerator.current;
        console.log("Task: " + task.get_id() + " - " + task.get_name());
    }
}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetMyTasksFail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed to get tasks. Error:' + args.get_message());
}


</script>
```

Edit 1: Here is the new Version of my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sps10/EDV/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

    var context, userSessionManager, userSession, query, myTasks;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var scriptbase = "https://www.example.at/_layouts/15/"
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.runtime.js", function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.js", function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.workmanagement.js", test)
            });
        });
    });

    function test() {

        context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        userSessionManager = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.UserOrderedSessionManager(context);
        userSession = userSessionManager.createSession();
        query = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.TaskQuery(context);
        myTasks = userSession.readTasks(query);

        getMyTasks();

    }


    function getMyTasks() {
        context.load(myTasks);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetMyTasksSuccess, onGetMyTasksFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    function onGetMyTasksSuccess() {
        console.log("Successfully retrieved tasks...");
        alert("fudhokn");
        var taskEnumerator = myTasks.getEnumerator();
        while (taskEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var task = taskEnumerator.current;
            console.log("Task: " + task.get_id() + " - " + task.get_name());
        }
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetMyTasksFail(sender, args) {
        console.log('Failed to get tasks. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }

</script>
```

So any help or advise would be great. If you want i can post my Code with the rest-api too but the error stays the same.

Thanks for your help and time.

Edit 2: Working solution to query my Task with a plain html: The important things are to load the `scr` in the right order and to use the jquery-min and not the normal jquery.

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.workmanagement.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    'use strict';

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var userSessionManager = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.UserOrderedSessionManager(context);
    var userSession = userSessionManager.createSession();
    var query = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.TaskQuery(context);
    var myTasks = userSession.readTasks(query);


        getMyTasks();


    function getMyTasks() {
        context.load(myTasks);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetMyTasksSuccess, onGetMyTasksFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    function onGetMyTasksSuccess() {
        console.log("Successfully retrieved tasks...");
        var taskEnumerator = myTasks.getEnumerator();
        while (taskEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var task = taskEnumerator.current;
            console.log("Task: " + task.get_id() + " - " + task.get_name());
        }
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetMyTasksFail(sender, args) {
        console.log('Failed to get tasks. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }

</script>
```

For the aspx version refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works fine in ASPX page not sure about HTML page.

Microsoft did some changes in the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method in **SharePoint 2013** and renamed it to be `executeFunc.

**Example:**

**SharePoint 2013 Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var context, userSessionManager ,userSession , query , myTasks ;
$(document).ready(function () {
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
       context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
           userSessionManager = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.UserOrderedSessionManager(context);
           userSession = userSessionManager.createSession();
           query = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.TaskQuery(context);
           myTasks = userSession.readTasks(query);
       }, "sp.workmanagement.js");
       getMyTasks();
   });
});

function getMyTasks() {
    context.load(myTasks);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetMyTasksSuccess, onGetMyTasksFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
function onGetMyTasksSuccess() {
    console.log("Successfully retrieved tasks...");
    var taskEnumerator = myTasks.getEnumerator();
    while (taskEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var task = taskEnumerator.current;
        console.log("Task: " + task.get_id() + " - " + task.get_name());
    }
}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetMyTasksFail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed to get tasks. Error:' + args.get_message());
}


</script>
```

**Reference**

[SP.ClientContext object (sp.js)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245759.aspx)

Update all JS references with below code in your page.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink1" runat="server" Name="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink2" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink3" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink4" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/15/sp.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink5" runat="server" Name="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink6" runat="server" Name="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink7" runat="server" Name="/sps10/EDV/jquery.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
```

**Note:-**

Kindly download external JS files, place them to some folder (Layouts) & replace the reference in above code with that new location.

Comment: now it says SOD is undefiened.....

Comment: SP.SOD works tightly together with the ScriptLink server control. ScriptLink is a SharePoint server control for registering java script files.
**<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink1" runat="server" Name="My_Script.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />**. This is just a sample but you need to change your JS link in above code.

Comment: Is that worked for you? Please let me know is you have any issues.

Comment: well i try to google for it what you mean but no clue. Sorry i am a complete beginner with sharepoint.

Comment: Have you tried to change the references of your JS files as per the example given in my comment?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: well the runat="server" is only usable on ASP.net Files. I just got an HTML File where i try to query myTask. Or need i another File?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42041/discussion-between-hardik-and-andreas-a).

Comment: works like a blast thx